# Handling Facebook authorization -- what's with the "state" parameter coming back from auth?

Tags: authentication, facebook

The Facebook API is not my friend today...

I'm trying to work out the basics of FB authorization, especially handling both cases of the user allowing and not allowing the app to have access to the requested permissions.  (I had a working login scheme with fb:login-button, except for the "don't allow" part, which doesn't seem to be possible with fb:login-button.)

The problem: When the user Allows access, my server gets two hits:

- A POST from Facebook to my app's post_authorization callback, which contains a signed_request that, I guess, will eventually be used to get to the user's access token, and
- a GET, from my own site, of the form "GET /?state=aLongStringOfEncodedCharacters".

I can't find any explanation of this GET call or the "state" parameter -- this seems to be one of the places where the FB documentation has, um, evolved recently.  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ refers to a GET returning a "code" parameter; my application definition on Facebook references the post_authorization callback, but it's not mentioned anywhere in the authentication page.  Arggh.  Can anybody out there explain what's going on, and how I can get this authentication process resolved?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You receive both, `code` parameter and `state`, too. `code` parameter lets you to get an access_token, by getting this URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
       client_id=YOURAPPID&
       redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL&
       client_secret=YOUR_SECRET&
       code=CODE_PARAM_YOU_RECEIVED;
```

The `state` parameter is CSFR protection.

If you look at this code (taken from the page you posted),

```
   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
         //getting access_token here      
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }
```

you'll see that you (or at least this example) sends some `md5()` hashed random string to Facebook.

You should be checking whether it is the same with the one you received, if not, you/your client might be a victim of CSFR

Comment: Aaaah -- now I see it ("code", that is). All those random characters look alike after awhile...  Thanks much!; I'll check into this.

Comment: OK, there's been some progress -- I almost have the exact code from the FB authorization page working (as a temp exercise).  The problem, now, is that the call to @file_get_contents($token_url) is failing to return anything; $token_url itself looks properly formed.  But then there's this whole thing with that POST coming in from FB with a signed_request, which sure seems to have an access token inside of it, and that's the whole point of doing this token_url call - to get the user's access token.  Am I supposed to get the access token from the POST instead of what's documented here?

Comment: No, do not get anything with their POST request. I'm not sure why it happens, but I'm sure it's nothing useful if it's an internal request. Check if your PHP directive `allow_url_fopen` is true, also remove the *at* (`@`) sign, which will might show you an error which you need in order to make it work.

Comment: More progress, of a sort: My problem seems to be in the DIALOG url -- in my server logs, the handling of the dialog/permissions.request call is throwing a "CSRF state token does not match one provided" error, via getCode() down in the FB php library.  Some debugging statements show that the REQUEST is OK, but the Facebook object, for some reason, doesn't have any value for the STATE variable.  Thus it dies, and somehow or another screws up everything else.  IN particular, the call to $token_url fails to return an access token.  I'm digging deeper..

Comment: Not very easily, to be honest -- it's a whole site.  The authentication part, which is all that's in question, is exactly what's in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication.  Thanks very much for your help; I'll continue to dig into this, and report back if I learn anything.

Comment: @JimMiller: Do you use some kind of SDK?

Comment: I'm using the "standard" php DSK (3.1.1).

Comment: @JimMiller: so I assume you use FB sdk to authenticate. Please post a code you use

Comment: Again, it's exactly the code that's shown in the Facebook doc.  I'm currently assuming that either (a) the API and doc are out of sync (e.g., there's no reference to that POST coming back from FB with the access token in it) or (b) there's something else altogether going on.  I'll report back if/when I learn anything.  For now, I've reverted to using fb:login-button, which at least gets me logged in (but without handling for the "Don't Allow") condition, which started this whole thing...

Comment: @JimMiller: I'd like to solve this. Please try to change this in base_facebook - getCode function - `var_dump($this->state, $_SESSION['state']);` If you have some time, I could assist you on Skype, I'm really looking forward to solve this

Comment: Thanks for the offer; I'm traveling right now, but I may be able to dig into this more next week.  I'll post what I can then.

Comment: I'm expecting the same issue. Some people say that answer hides in developers.facebook basic setting fields - App. Domain & Site URL. ...but still digging with no results

Answer (score 0):

`FBRLH_state` session is not set, this hash could be find in `$_GET['state']`;

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state'] = $_GET['state'];
```